# How to MLE estimation of LogNormal data with right-censored failure times?

Tags: statistics

So far the examples that I have found are with "complete" failure data.  But in my line of work, my data includes failure times from units and times from units that have not failed yet (right-censored).  I was wondering if someone can point me to some reference material on how to calculate the LogNormal parameters using MLE method when my data includes censored data.

EDIT: I should add that in the end, what I need is the Newton-Raphson equation to numerically solve the Log-Normal parameters or some other numerical algorithm since there is no closed-form solution to obtain the parameters directly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics.